# Using native code with Libgdx, (Raknet)

Tags: libgdx, networking, multiplayer, cross-platform

I was searching for a game engine (Java- maybe C#) with built-in real time networking library to develop 2D cross platform (Android - iOS) multiplayer game. Actually I have not found well suited solution apart from Unity, however I don't like some of the features of Unity. ([Here is Discussion](http://www.reddit.com/r/gamedev/comments/1llroq/should_i_make_the_switch_from_libgdx_to_unity/))

After a while I decided to use Libgdx and tried to find a network libray that meets my requirements and I found Raknet as network engine which is written in C++ and cross-platform. So here is my question:

**Is there any way to use Raknet with Libgdx, or any other solutions you recommend as engine or anything else? And also is it possible to use any C/++ library with Libgdx like Android's NDK?**

Answer (score 2):

There is little to no documentation on it, but LibGDX does have a platform independant (Android, Desktop, iOS and GWT) socket class.

http://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/Net.html

and if you dont want to mesh with you can try kryonet networking library

https://code.google.com/p/kryonet/